# mysql select 3days records from today

Tags: mysql, date, select

```
SELECT * FROM `user` 
WHERE name !='' AND `date_created` BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 3 Day ) 
AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 0 Day ) 
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

The above query brings record 3day before from todays date.

but i need 3day records from today,which means tomorrow , day after tomorrow etc.

date_created is mysql date format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `user` 
WHERE name !='' 
AND `date_created` BETWEEN curdate() and curdate() + interval 3 day
ORDER BY `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this will return previous 3 days record

```
select * from events where DATEOFEVENT IN (select date(curdate()-3 ))
```